# web crawling in python to dart; re, bs4 to http & parser library in dart

Tags: html, json, parsing, dart

I would like to inquire if my Dart syntax is correct.
I'm trying to crawl three numbers in website and this is what I get when I parse.html

```
<!-- corona  virus number--> <div class="co_cur"> 
<p class="tit">corona virus number<a href="/bdBoardList.do"> </a></p> 
<ul> <li><span class="tit">Corona number</span><a class="num" href="/bdBoardList.do">5,328</a></li> 
<li><span class="tit">Recovered number</span><a class="num" href="/bdBoardList.do">41</a></li>
<li><span class="tit">Death number</span><a class="num" href="/bdBoardList.do">32</a></li> </ul>
```

This is my python code

```
html = requests.get("http://ncov.mohw.go.kr/index_main.jsp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser") 
data = soup.select("div.co_cur > ul > li > a.num") ##go to here
regex = re.compile(r"\d[,\d]+") ##reg
cc = regex.search(data[0].text).group() #5328
recovered = regex.search(data[1].text).group() #41
dead = regex.search(data[2].text).group() #32
```

This is my dart code. Since I'm new to dart, I have followed [thisblog](https://creativebracket.com/write-your-first-web-scraper/) and [dartdocument](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#darthtml), but not sure if this is correct. Especially if the use of Element and group syntax is correct.

```
import 'dart:convert'; 
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

Future initiate(BaseClient client) async { 
    // Make API call to site 
    Response response = await client.get('http://ncov.mohw.go.kr/index_main.jsp'); 

    if (response.statusCode != 200) return response.body; 

    // Use html parser 
    var document = parse(response.body); 
    List<dom.Element> num = document.querySelectorAll("div.co_cur > ul > li > a.num"); 
    //do i use dom.Element or just Element?

    regex = RegExp(r"\d[,\d]+");
    match = regexp.allMatches(num);
    ncorona = match.group(0);  //is this syntax is correct?
    nrecovered = match.group(1);
    ndeath = match.group(2);

    return ncorona, nrecovered, ndeath
```

Comment: Please specify your problem so we can help you. Right now your Dart code is not even valid but looks like you have combined Python and Dart. E.g. Dart does not support returning multiple values.

Comment: I'd like to inquire if the syntax of Dart code is correct. Right now, my dart code seems pseudo code for me too...